# I want to insert few location in to java script array using a another array

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This function gets the total distance among few locations. Normally it works with this array without following getLocations array and for loop.

```
waypoints: [{location: 'Galle'},{location: 'Kandy'},{location: 'minneriya wildlife park'}, {location: 'Horton Plains'}],
```

Now I want to insert those location into getLocations array using for loop like following:

```
function getDistance() {

    var getLocations = ['Galle','Kandy', 'minneriya wildlife park', 'Horton Plains'];

    var request = {
        origin: getLocations[0],
        destination: getLocations[0],
        for (var i = 0; i < getLocations.length; i++) { 
            waypoints = [{location :getLocations[i]}]
        }

        waypoints,travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Now it's not work properly. I surf the internet for the solution and couldn't find. please help me. I want to know that how it work proper way. Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example contains the error, in particular at line where `request` object is initialized, `waypoints` array could not be initialized that way. One option would be to place the `waypoints` array initialization outside of `request` object initialization as demonstrated below.

**Fixed example**

```js
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    getDistance();
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}


function getDistance() {
    var locations = ['Galle', 'Kandy', 'minneriya wildlife park', 'Horton Plains'];

    var waypoints = locations.map(function(loc) {
        return { 'location': loc };
    });

    var request = {
        origin: locations[0],
        destination: locations[0],
        waypoints: waypoints,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };


    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```